Can you expose groups with Form Builder?
I am creating a form using form builder. I want to expose two groups (mailing lists) to create an email sign up form where users can subscribe to groups by checking boxes.
Can I do that using form builder?

This was recently introduced in CiviCRM 5.77, 'Group Subscriptions' is one of the entities you can select from the + menu in the tabs. From there you can configure it with a number of options, i.e. which groups to make available to subscribe, unsubscribe; if email verification is required, etc.


This is great, but is it possible to change the label?

Not in FormBuilder I don't think - it uses the default public title for the group as far as I'm aware.
